# Why exactly doesn't HTML5 Media Source video work on IOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

It seems both (`HLS` and `MPEG-DASH`) use the same the `Media Source Extension` API. So why does HLS `video` only work on IOS. Why doesn't `MPEG-DASH` work on IOS? What is the core difference making this "http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html" `video` not work on IOS? Where is the problem? Is it the `new MediaSource`, `.addSourceBuffer`, `.appendBuffer`, `.endOfStream()` or `.mp4` file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only apple can answer that, and so far they have not commented.

> EDIT: iPadOS 13 will/does support MSE. iOS 14.5 (iPhone) still doesn't
> not.

Comment: There is nothing to debug. It is a fact that apple does not support MSE in iOS. The extension hence API simply doesn’t exist in the browser.

Comment: The thing is i want to make a HLS video player from scratch. And i can’t find a specific source showing beginning steps of how to make a HLS video player. As in I made a DASH type video player using this http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html. It clearly shows how the video is retrieved and appended into the player. I can’t find a similar source like this for making a HLS player. What should i do? Do i have no choice but to use a pre made hls.js (its just i don’t know how to customise it then for my specific needs, its so long)?

Comment: It doesn’t matter what you want to do. There is no way to do that on safari on iOS. The ONLY way to play video in safari on iOS is to set the src filed in the video tag to the m3u8 or mp4 file.

Comment: I want to make a web video playe for IOS which can switch the video’s type (2d or 3d), video quality (2160p to 144p), video fps (60fps to 30fps), audio and subtitles (English to french). I have a video file and i have converted the video into different video files of all the above switching types. Wait ill upload my project. So can m3u8 switch things like this?

Comment: This is an new question. Please make a new post.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036652/how-to-make-a-hls-video-player-from-my-custom-make-dash-like-video-player

Comment: What do you think of the new post?

Comment: szatmary - Can you help me with this question? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586596/how-to-create-video-and-audio-files-for-the-media-source-extension-api

Answer (score 3):

New information:  Our iPhone, 16.5.1, has support for MediaSource, tucked behind an experimental flag.  Default setting is 'off'.

When turned on, it seems to work about the same as the iPad.

---

Edit: Oct 2023

Beta iOS 17 is out and Apple has pulled MediaSource from Safari.  In its place, there is an implementation for a [new proposed alternative standard API called Managed Media Source (MMS)](https://github.com/w3c/media-source/issues/320). The alternate API can better manage battery life that the previous Media Source Extension (MSE) API.

Comment: `MediaSource` class exists, yes, but it seems like `MediaSource.isTypeSupported` returns false for all values: https://cconcolato.github.io/media-mime-support/ (tested on iOS 16.6)