# How to create video and audio files for the Media Source Extension API?

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I have created a video player from the `Media Source Extension API`. I have split the `video` and `audio` from the `original.mp4 (1 minute duration)`. I have split the `video` and `audio` into small `5 second files (12 files in total)`. I'm getting each one of them and playing them together. But the video stops playing at around 45-47 seconds. I cannot understand to why the video is stopping/buffering. I cannot understand whether the problem is in the `javascript` code or the video files?

I have uploaded all the resources here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NHc_yNRU0tvaU18aohLy74Js3y7UHD4N/view?usp=sharing). And written the commands I used to construct my video and audio files below. I have also noticed that this problem only occurs with `Google Chrome` and works perfectly and smoothly on `Microsoft Edge`. Thanks

`Making the Media files:`

`Extracting video from original.mp4: MP4Box -single 1 original.mp4`

`Extracting audio from original.mp4: MP4Box -single 2 original.mp4`

`Splitting the video and audio into 5 second parts: ffmpeg -ss` starting-time `-to` end-time `-i` (video.mp4 `OR` audio.mp4) (video_**part**.mp4 `OR` audio_**part**.mp4)

`Fragmenting all the video and audio parts: MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap`(video_**part**.mp4 `OR` audio_**part**.mp4)

`Then using the fragmented video and audio files to be played via the Media Source Extension API video player.` e.g. (video_part_dashinit.mp4 `OR` audio_part_dashinit.mp4)

Comment: I have noticed something, this problem only occurs in Google Chrome, but not in Microsoft Edge.